# How to make/develop Android apps and use them with RPi4?

Tags: raspbian, android, pi-4, android-things

I am using *Raspberry Pi 4* for a while with the latest buster release. I searched for a lot of questions and find that *Android* development is not possible with *Raspberry Pi*. But I wonder, that both are powered by *Linux*.

Is there any way to make an *Android* app and run it with either *Raspbian* or with *Android* mobile directly?

Comment: `run it with either raspbian Please clarify what you mean with `with`. Do you mean to run an Android app on a Pi running Raspbian? Or something else?

Comment: The first one you said

Comment: This is really a general linux question which you should ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  The answer for linux generally, though, is no, except in the emulator (usually used as part of Android Studio), which I doubt will run on any model of Pi.  That "they are both powered by linux" is true in the sense that they both use the same OS kernel.  However, the Android *userland* and the GNU *userland* (used in GNU/Linux distros such as Debian and Rasbpian) are very incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi) if you are just looking into having the pi run a single application. 
As of right now, this is the only supported way of putting android onto a pi. (as far as i know).

There are other options such as [LineageOS](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi3/CM14.1/), but these tend to run pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

> I searched for a lot of questions and find that android development is not possible with raspberry pi.

It is possible to develop *Android* applications for *Raspberry Pi 3 model B* running [*Android Things*](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started). Unfortunately, *Raspberry Pi 4* is not yet [officially supported by Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms).